# Работа unity приложения при сворачивании и отключении экрана Android

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Пишу приложение на unity под Android для учета времени(TimeTrack). В приложении запускается таймер для установленных пользователем целей. Как сделать так что бы таймер продолжал работать когда приложение свернуто или отключен экран. Подскажите как решить или что загуглить.

Comment: ну например "андроид работа в фоне" или типа того

Comment: Зачем гонять таймер, когда приложение выключено? Проще и лучше при восстановлении фокуса смотреть на системное время и просчитывать сколько прошло времени в "свернутом/выключенном" состоянии и обновлять таймер относительно этой величины.

Comment: А в случае если нужно будет отправлять уведомление пользователю по истечению установленного времени?